# Prove that $(g \circ f)^* = f^* \circ g^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Assume $g: F \mapsto G$ is a linear map

Prove that $(g \circ f)^* = f^* \circ g^*$

My solution

$(g \circ f)^* = g^* \circ f^*$ by the properties of associativity in linear maps.

If we assume that $g^* \circ f^* = f^* \circ g^* $ then $g$ and $f$ are inverse functions of each other.

By the properties of linear maps the only way that $g^* \circ f^* = f^* \circ g^*$ is if they are inverse functions.

therefore $(g \circ f)^* = f^* \circ g^*$

is there anything wildly wrong with my reasoning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following anon's interpretation,  $(g\circ f)^\star$ is a map from $G^\star$, the dual space to $G$, to $F^\star$.

We have $(g\circ f)^\star (\phi)=\phi\circ (g\circ f)$.  By associativity of composition, this equals $(\phi \circ g)\circ f$, which equals $f^\star(\phi \circ g)=f^\star(g^\star(\phi))=(f^\star \circ g^\star)(\phi)$.  Hence we have proved $(g\circ f)^\star=f^\star \circ g^\star$ on every element of the domain; hence the functions are equal.

Comment: thanks that helps. Sometimes my prof doesn't say what various notations mean and getting contradictory answers in this class is a depressing reality. If I never take a math class again it will be too soon afte rthis.